# PyOpenCL - 'Build succeeded, but resulted in non-empty logs'

Tags: python, opencl, pyopencl

I just started using PyOpenCL and OpenCL in general (coming from CUDA).
Thing is, when I'm using this very simple dummy kernel:

```
typedef struct type_complex64
{
   float real;
   float imag;
} complex64;

__kernel void transform(__global complex64* amps, __constant complex64* operator)
{
    unsigned int i = get_global_id(0);

    amps[i].real = 1.0f;
    amps[i].imag = 0.0f;
}
```

I get this at the build step:

> C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyopencl\cache.py:338: UserWarning:
>   Build succeeded, but resulted in non-empty logs: Build on
>   pyopencl.Device '       Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2410M CPU @
>   2.30GHzC:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyopencl__init__.py:173: UserWarning: Build succeeded, but resulted in non-empty logs: Build on
>   pyopencl.Device '       Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2410M CPU @ 2.30GHz

And here I don't even get back my interpreter command prompt, I have to press Enter to return to the prompt. I guess there's supposed to be some actual message, but I can't get it to show up. 
BTW the kernel runs fine, so no problems there. This is fairly annoying. Any ideas what this might be?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'I can't get it to show up.'  Are you calling the pyopencl equivalent of `clGetProgramBuildInfo` to examine the build log?  My guess is that you're getting compilation warnings, but not errors.

Comment: I mean that I tried different Python prompts (standard, IPython, IDLE) but the output is the same always, like it's not finished and I have to press Enter to get a prompt again. I use CL like this:
`self.program = cl.Program(self.ctx, self.sourceString).build()`
I guess PyOpenCL wraps it automatically with a log query and displays it.